# SQL Server spatial STIntersection()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, spatial

I have two geometries, when i try to get STIntersection from these two geometries, sql server return output of Exception.

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.Combine(CombineMode combineMode, GeoData g1, GeoData g2)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STIntersection(SqlGeometry other).
```

I am trying to STIntersection on two polygons, which one of them has 51536 points from STNumPoints and the other one has 3125.

I tried it with this select:

```
declare @geomHnv geometry = ( select top 1 Shape from dbo.hnv)
declare @geomSaps geometry = ( select top 1 Shape from dbo.Saps)
select @geomSaps.STNumPoints()



select o1.Shape.STIntersection(o2.Shape)
from dbo.hnv o1
cross join dbo.saps o2
```

The polygon is so big, that i cannot copy it here, so i made a backup of database with only two polygons from above.

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Vv9ogG99P-YmZSNkFDLUpZb3M

Dump consist of two tables, where each table contains one geometry column.

I tried it on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: "The polygon is so big, that i cannot copy it here" - an obvious thing to do is to determine whether size alone is a factor or something else. Are you able to reproduce the issue using a *simpler* polygon? (If you have tried this, it would at least be worth mentioning it)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I tried to run intersection on big polygon(51k points) and simple polygon(4 points) and it did not throw an exception. When i run other spatial functions(intersects, crosses, touches) with original polygons they work as they should. Only intersection function throws exception. i also tried different SRID for polygons

Comment: Any chance you could put the WKB ow WKT for these polygons somewhere? I'm stuck on SQL 2012 here and would like to help!